# How to update same input with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to droppable area with same name, I need input for each to save it then in different places. The problem is its just creating new input after clicking save button but I need to update already existing input and creating new one.
You can see [sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/97u0peju/167/)
I am using this function to create input for each of the boxes. in my work it can be even more than 2. It depends on user's input:

```
var LISTOBJ = {
    saveList: function() {
        $(".projLeader").each(function() {
            var listCSV = [];
            $(this).find("li").each(function(){
                listCSV.push($(this).text());
            });
            var values = listCSV.join(', ');
            $(".output").append("<input type='text' name='projLeader[]' value='"+values+"' /></br>");
            console.debug(listCSV);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code, might be help you.

```
        var LISTOBJ = {
        saveList: function() {
          $(".output").html("");
            $(".projLeader").each(function() {
              var listCSV = [];
              $(this).find("li").each(function(){
                  listCSV.push($(this).text());
              });
              var values = listCSV.join(', ');
              $(".output").append("<input type='text' name='projLeader[]' value='"+values+"' /></br>");
                  console.debug(listCSV);                     

            });
          }
        }
```

Comment: is it what you looking for or need something else ??

Comment: Let me check it inside my system, in fiddle seems like yes. So you just clear `output` every  time before appending values again right?

Comment: yes the above  code do the same. every time clear all inputbox and add new with new values.